# Show confirm dialog before delete node of jstree

Tags: jquery-ui, webforms, jquery-ui-dialog, jstree

I use jstree and jquery-ui v1.10.1 .I use context menu on tree and i want before delete node show confirm dialog(like jquery-ui dialog).
I use dialog in "before.jstree" event, but when show dialog box, before an option is selected(yes or no) ,the selected node is deleted.
How to solve this problem?

```
.bind("before.jstree", function(e, data) {
                  if (data.func === "remove") {
                      if (!confirmRemove()) {
                          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                          return false;
                      }
                  }
              }

function confirmRemove() {
return  $confirmDialog.dialog('open');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the 2.1.0 version and there is another solution for this functionality.

What you have to do is add a function to the check_callback option. 
Like this:

```
        $("#your_tree").jstree({
        "core": {
            "check_callback": function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
                // operation can be 'create_node', 'rename_node', 'delete_node', 'move_node', 'copy_node' or 'edit'
                // in case of 'rename_node' node_position is filled with the new node name
                if (operation === 'delete_node') {
                    if (!confirmRemove()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I know that this is an old question, but i looked for a more recent question/answer and didn't find it.

Hope it helps to other people that will have the same question :)

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery-UI-Dialog is asynchronous; If you call it, your eventhandler does not stop execution and waits, but goes on and deletes the Node.

Try the JavaScript-Dialog confirm() since this is synchronous and stops further execution until the User confirmed or declined the Dialog.